# Can the second law of thermodynamics be written as $\delta Q \leq T \mathrm{d} S$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy, work

Can the second law of thermodynamics for a system be written as follows?$$\delta Q \leq T \mathrm{d} S$$

Where $T$ should be the temperature of the **system**.

I'm not sure about this because we are considering a generic process (so also irreversible) here, hence it is not necessarily true that the temperatures of system and environment are the same.

But I saw that this form of second law is used to get to

$$\delta W \leq - (\mathrm{d}U-T \mathrm{d}S)$$

And define thermodynamics potentials ($F,G,H..$)

So it should be correct, but are there limitations on writing the second law like that?

Comment: no, in general, it cannot be written as $\delta Q \le TdS$ where $T$ is the system temperature because only for *reversible* processes $T_{system}=T_{reservoir}$ in which case  $\delta Q = TdS$ otherwise when $T_{system} \ne T_{reservoir}$ you have $\delta Q < T_{reservoir}dS$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, that makes more sense. Nevertheless, referring to $$\delta W \leq - (\mathrm{d}U-T \mathrm{d}S) \tag{1}$$

I found a proof here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_work#Thermodynamics, where the temperature $T$ is considered the one of the resevoir indeed, but at the end the inequality is written as in $(1)$, where $T$ is (since nothing is specified) the temperature of the system. How is that possible?

Comment: your wikipeda reference defines (correctly)  $T$ as the temperature of the reservoir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second law of thermodynamics cannot be written in this way because the inequality in question is not even wrong (the entropy term is not defined). The entropy is only definable for irreversible processes if they start and end in equilibrium, and gas expansion is the only such process. See this:

http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/archive/00000313/ 
Jos Uffink, Bluff your Way in the Second Law of Thermodynamics, p.39: "A more important objection, it seems to me, is that Clausius bases his conclusion that the entropy increases in a nicht umkehrbar [irreversible] process on the assumption that such a process can be closed by an umkehrbar [reversible] process to become a cycle. This is essential for the definition of the entropy difference between the initial and final states. But the assumption is far from obvious for a system more complex than an ideal gas, or for states far from equilibrium, or for processes other than the simple exchange of heat and work. Thus, the generalisation to all transformations occurring in Nature is somewhat rash."